# Display columns and rows after exporting data from gridview to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

Hi all i am having a task to export gridview data to excel which i have done using the forums and articles available.

But i would like to display complete `excel columns` after the data was imported to excel, means expect the place occupied by the grid content i would like to display the remaining columns of the excel as it is.

Sample the normal way of exporting the we do in common is as follows

[image]

My requirement is to show as follows

[image]

I followed as per here

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-To-Word-Excel-PDF-CSV-Formats-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: delete //Change the Header Row back to white color

GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF"); and //Change Color back to white

    row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

Comment: Even then it just remove the back ground color and the styles applied but i can not get what i required right

Answer (score 0):

See your code to export you have removed the border of the excel generated in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to do it

```
protected void btnExportCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    Response.Clear();

    Response.Buffer = true;

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",

     "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.csv");

    Response.Charset = "";

    Response.ContentType = "application/text";



    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

    GridView1.DataBind();



    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)

    {

        //add separator

        sb.Append(GridView1.Columns[k].HeaderText + ',');

    }

    //append new line

    sb.Append("\r\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

    {

        for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)

        {

            //add separator

            sb.Append(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text + ',');

        }

        //append new line

        sb.Append("\r\n");

    }

    Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());

    Response.Flush();

    Response.End();

}
-->Return only hearder,not view data.Help Me !
Thank you !
Email:tsmcstcd@gmail.com
```